# Multiple sequential API calls using RXJS in Angular 12 app

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a requirement where, once I get a response from my first API call, I need to make 2 API calls (can be in parallel). Once all the API call's response is got, I need to send the observables (obs2$ & obs3$) to the subcomponent.

Code is something like:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.obs1$ = this.getData1();
    this.obs2$ = this.obs1$.pipe(
        concatMap(() => {
            return this.getData2();
        })
    );
    this.obs3$ = this.obs1$.pipe(
        concatMap(() => {
            return this.getData3();
        })
    );
}

private getData1(): Observable<string> {
    return this.service.getData1<string>('/api/get_1').pipe(
        tap((response: string) => {
            this.id = response
        })
    );
}

private getData2(): Observable<string> {
    return this.service.getData2<string>('/api/get_2/id='+this.id).pipe(
        tap((response: string) => {
            ...
            this.flag2 = true;
        })
    );
}

private getData3(): Observable<string> {
    return this.service.getData3<string>('/api/get_3/id='+this.id).pipe(
        tap((response: string) => {
            ...
            this.flag3 = true;
        })
    );
}
```

My .html is like this:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="(data2: obs2$ | async, data3: obs3$ | async) as data; else loading">
    <ng-container *ngIf="flag2 && flag3; else loading">
        <sub-component
            [data2]="data.data2"
            [data3]="data.data3"
        >
        <sub-component>
    </ng-container>
</ng-container>
<ng-template #loading> Loading... </ng-template>
```

The issue is API call of getData1 is getting called 2 times. Is there a way to have it in single. Also, if I can do it without using the flags (flag 2 & flag3).
Note: I tried this, but it did not work:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.obs1$ = this.getData1();
    this.obs1$.pipe(first()).subscribe(() => {
        this.obs2$ = this.getData2();
        this.obs3$ = this.getData3();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're almost there. Instead of triggering individual calls for `data2` and `data3`, you could use the RxJS [`forkJoin`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/forkJoin) function to trigger multiple observables in parallel.

You could also skip the variables `id`, `flag2` and `flag3` this way.

Try the following

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.obs$ = this.getData1().pipe(
    switchMap((id: string) => forkJoin({
      data2: this.getData2(id),
      data3: this.getData3(id)
    }))
  );
}

private getData1(): Observable<string> {
  return this.service.getData1<string>('/api/get_1');
}

private getData2(id: string): Observable<string> {
  return this.service.getData2<string>('/api/get_2/id=' + id);
}

private getData3(id: string): Observable<string> {
  return this.service.getData3<string>('/api/get_3/id=' + id);
}
```

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="(obs$ | async) as data; else loading">
  <sub-component 
    [data2]="data.data2" 
    [data3]="data.data3"
  >
  <sub-component>
</ng-container>
<ng-template #loading> Loading... </ng-template>
```

Comment: Thanks Michael. I was able to use your solution

Answer (score 1):

If you need the `obs2$` & `obs3$` to be called on parallel with one HTTP request for `obs1$`, you can achieve that by adding the [shareReplay](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/shareReplay) operator to the `obs1$`.

Try it like the following:

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.obs1$ = this.getData1().pipe(shareReplay(1));
  this.obs2$ = this.obs1$.pipe(switchMap((id) => this.getData2(id)));
  this.obs3$ = this.obs1$.pipe(switchMap((id) => this.getData3(id)));
}

private getData1(): Observable<string> {
  return this.service.getData1<string>('/api/get_1');
}

private getData2(id: string): Observable<string> {
  return this.service.getData2<string>('/api/get_2/id=' + id);
}

private getData3(id: string): Observable<string> {
  return this.service.getData3<string>('/api/get_3/id=' + id);
}
```

Then regarding the flags, you can try the following within the template:

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="{ data2: obs2$ | async, data3: obs3$ | async } as data; else loading">
  <ng-container *ngIf="data.data2 && data.data3; else loading">
    <sub-component [data2]="data.data2" [data3]="data.data3"></sub-component>
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
<ng-template #loading> Loading... </ng-template>
```

Comment: Thanks Amer. I tried your solution, but, 'getData3' method is not called. I even used shareReplay(2).

Comment: It should work, please check it again if you missed anything.

Comment: I double checked. The issue is still present. Please note: I use tap to manipulate the observer (in all 3 getData methods) and I tried changing the sequence (interchanged getData2 and getData3). Still getData3 was not getting called

Comment: Check it here please: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-s1rtdk

Comment: Thanks for your help. My mistake, I had missed to put async pipe for obs3$ in html.